# SQLite UPDATE multiple rows in a column with a single value except one row (something like invert selection) : flutter

Tags: database, sqlite, flutter, sqflite

I have a list of objects that only one of them can be selected.
For this I have a column in this table (table of objects) that shows the status of the object (selected or not selected)
I want to select the item to be clicked and change the status to the selected mode and uncheck the other items.

what is the solution in sqlite/sqflite flutter?

Comment: Something like `update yourtable set status=0 where id <> ?`

Comment: @Shawn | maybe! but I can't pass ids manualy in <>

Comment: `<>` is not equals in SQL... Want a better answer, you're going to have to give more information like the schema of your table.

Comment: @Shawn | Could you explain complete soulution? thanks

Comment: Do you not know how UPDATE works?

Answer (score 0):

I don't know Flutter. A conditional update in SQL can look like this:

```
update mytable set selected = case when id = 123 then 1 else 0 end;
```